# Creating different stylesheet for CSS3 seperated from main stylesheet

Tags: css

In my web project, I made an extra CSS file (for example css3.css) only for CSS3 properties. That means I separated the CSS3 code from my main CSS file (style.css). It helps me maintain the CSS3 properties for cross browser compatibility issues.

What kind of problems, if any, will this create for my website? What kind of problems, if any, will this create in terms of maintenance?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that will work. CSS works cascading, meaning what come later overrules what comes before. So if you first load your default stylesheet and later your css3 stylesheet, you might overwrite some properties. Which might not be wishful. Personally, I like to keep it all in one file (or for bigger websites one basic stylesheet and seperat stylesheet for the pages).

Comment: I think you raise a good question about creating separate stylesheets. If you don't mind, I'll edit your question to fit the rules.

Comment: Thanks much for your comment. Oh no ! I must load css3.css file first and then my main stylesheet. So, the css3 codes might not be overriden. @ LinkinTED

Comment: You won't receive anymore answers. The question has been put on hold by community moderators.

Comment: @mbnyc you edited the post. But the put on hold badge is not disappeared, why? and why did the post get downvote ? I don't know actually. please let me know

Comment: I would suggest you familiarize yourself with the nature of the hold, then the steps you can take to re-open the question.
(1) http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions (2)
http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions

Comment: Yea, that's the problem !! I really don't know the criteria. thanks much @mbnyc

Comment: The question of separating stylesheets, based on browsers, devices, rules (e.g. media queries) and other criteria is worth exploring. Granted, CSS level and browser compatibility are likely not common considerations, but feedback from the community may be instructive. Maybe this question should be re-opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because there is not a strict CSS2 vs. CSS3 separation, plus it would be a nightmare to maintain.

You want to address different browser vendors with post-processors like [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) for instance.

Or target different IE version via [conditional comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx).

On top of that, you should deliver a single, minified CSS file of your app, rather than many separate ones [unless you have good reasons for the split, e.g. loading a separate theme for mobile devices on slow connections].